# How to find an element by matching exact text of the element in Capybara

Tags: ruby, regex, capybara

I have following two elements in HTML

```
<a href="/berlin" >Berlin</a>
<a href="/berlin" >Berlin Germany </a>
```

I am trying to find the element by using following Capybara method

```
find("a", :text => "berlin")
```

Above will return two elements because both contains text berlin.

Is there a way to match exact text in Capybara ?

Comment: Capybara or nokogiri? Why is this tagged both?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use [Capybara's exact option](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/#Exactness):

```
Capybara.exact = true
```

Answer (score 150):

Use a regexp instead of a string for the value of the `:text` key:

```
find("a", :text => /\ABerlin\z/)
```

Check out the 'Options Hash' section of the `Method: Capybara::Node::Finders#all` [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders%3aall).

PS: text matches are case sensitive. Your example code actually raises an error:

```
find("a", :text => "berlin")
# => Capybara::ElementNotFound:
#    Unable to find css "a" with text "berlin"
```

Comment: It's terrible that this is the best answer. :cry:

Comment: why do we have \A and \z between Berlin?

Comment: how can I add a placeholder in the regex

Comment: This could have been handled by writing `click_link(link_text, :text => link_text)`

Comment: [This better-seeming answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60492251/199712) worked for me.

Answer (score 64):

Depending on which version of the gem you are using

```
find('a', text: 'Berlin', exact: true)
```

may be deprecated. In which case you would have to use

```
find('a', text: 'Berlin', match: :prefer_exact)
```

Answer (score 26):

You can do so too:

```
find('a', text: 'Berlin', exact_text: true)
```

That will find for CSS.

And using only `exact: true` instead of `exact_text` will show you a msg that `exact` option is only valid for XPATH.

Comment: or even more, you can use `find("a", exact_text: "berlin")`

Comment: This also works for other matchers like `have_button('Copy', exact: true)`.

Answer (score 6):

My preference is to use the `have_selector` with `text` and `exact_text: true`:

```
expect(body).to have_selector 'a', text: 'Berlin', exact_text: true
```

Answer (score 0):

For using click_link in capybara you need to add one more property in the method using it.

```
click_link(link_name, :text => link_name)
```

Here the **link_name** is the text value of a link. 
Using **:text** keyword we are specifying that we want to click on a link having the text value which is exact matching to our requirement.